# Right Iban but Wrong Swift Code

Tags: banking, transfer, swift, iban

I have sent some money (in euro) to Netherlands (ING Bank) from Turkey. The IBAN is correct but the swift code is INGBNL2AXXXX instead of INGBNL2AXXX. The recipient did not get the money and the money is not refunded to my account either. It's been two weeks. Can it be fixed during the process?

Comment: Contact your bank.

Comment: Here you can find the updated swift code list for Turkey Banka Swift Kodlari
https://www.desteklemeler.net/tum-bankalarin-guncel-swift-kodlari/

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with your Bank in Turkey. Generally depending on the software implemented by your Bank, the extra "X" will either get removed or the payment instruction will fall into a repair queue that the Operations from Bank in Turkey will see and remove the extra "X".

Comment: Many thanks. I am also charged for the intermediary bank fees on the day after the value date. When does the intermediary bank charges me? As soon as they recieve the swift message or after they credit the beneficiary bank?